# CGI::escapeHTML() doesn't work

Tags: html, cgi, mod-perl2, perl

I am new to CGI, my code output:

```
Hello, "<h1>Tom Cat</h1>"!
```

Seems the `escapeHTML()` doesn't work.

I develope my cgi code with XAMPP 1.7.2 on winxp. 
How can I fix it. Do I need download & install extra CGI Plugin for the current XAMPP? Appreciated for your help.

```
#!C:/Perl/bin/perl.exe -w


use strict; 
use CGI;

my $q = CGI->new();

print $q->header();
my $value = $q->param("myvar");

print $q->header();
print "<html><body>";
#print qq{Hello, "$value"!\n};
print qq{Hello, "}, CGI::escapeHTML($value), qq{"!\n};
print "</body></html>";
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is a terrible description of a problem. Try telling us what you expected to happen and what actually happened.

Comment: @davorg, I thought I need install `CGI::escapeHTML` on my dev environment. but I don't know how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What are you expecting it to do? escapeHTML takes your string and changes it so the what will display is what is in the string - it turns it into something else that your browser then turns back to the original test.

It would appear that your parameter "myvar" contains the <h1> tags, which escapeHTML turns into &lt;h1&gt;, so that your browser can restore the original text.

If you want it not to do this but to interpret the tags, you need *not* to escape it.